# Error Type: ADODB.Recordset (0x800A0E79) Operation is not allowed when the object is open

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, asp-classic

i am working on this code but it gives me an error saying thatError Type:
ADODB.Recordset (0x800A0E79)
Operation is not allowed when the object is open. I have never ever come across this error before. What i am trying to do is to update an access file when a new file is doped in a particular folder. I was doing the same thing with excel which was perfectly working, when i added the access part to it, it gave me the error. here is my code, it be nice if I could get some help.

```
<!--#include file="header.inc"-->
<%

file = Request.querystring("file")

file = "C:\Reports\" & file

log("UPDATE UTILITY RUN---------" & file)

'Initialize Connection to report

Const adOpenStatic = 3

Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set rows = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _

    "Data Source=" & file & ";" & _

        "Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1" & Chr(34) & ";"  


'Initlialize Connection to Data

Set objConnection2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set rows2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _

    "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data.xlsx") & ";" & _

        "Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0" & Chr(34) & ";"  


'initialize Connection3 to Data

Set objConnection3 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set rows3 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection3.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & 
Server.MapPath("tracker_dev_nik.accdb") & ";Persist Security Info=False;"       


'Query the spreadsheet

rows.Open "Select * FROM [WC-Stages$]", _

    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText



'Print off the row's data

DIM JUR

DIM WC

DIM WC_NAME

DIM PRIORITY

DIM REP

DIM DELIVER

DIM ACCEPT

DIM REJECT

DIM REDELIVER

DIM STATUS

DIM SDATE

DIM DATA_STATUS

DIM DATA_STATUS_2

DIM DATA_SDATE

DIM DATA_SDATE_2

Do Until rows.EOF

    JUR = rows.Fields("F3").Value

    WC = rows.Fields("F4").Value

    WC_NAME = rows.Fields("F5").Value

    PRIORITY = rows.Fields("F7").Value

    REP = rows.Fields("F23").Value

    DELIVER = rows.Fields("F22").Value

    ACCEPT = rows.Fields("F24").Value

    REJECT = rows.Fields("F25").Value

    REDELIVER = rows.Fields("F26").Value

    STATUS = ""

    SDATE = ""

    DATA_STATUS = ""

    DATA_SDATE = ""

    IF NOT ( JUR = "" OR JUR = "Jur" ) THEN 'Ignore invalid rows (first two and 

last three)

        If IsNull(DELIVER) THEN

            STATUS = "undelivered"

            SDATE = "1/1/2000"

        ELSE

            IF IsNull(ACCEPT) THEN

                IF IsNull(REJECT) THEN

                    STATUS = "delivered"

                    SDATE = DELIVER

                ELSE

                    IF IsNull(REDELIVER) THEN

                        STATUS = "rejected"

                        SDATE = REJECT

                    ELSE

                        STATUS = "redelivered"

                        SDATE = REDELIVER

                    END IF

                END IF

            ELSE

                STATUS = "accepted"

                SDATE = ACCEPT

            END IF

        END IF



        query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE JUR = '" & JUR & "' AND WC = " & WC

        rows2.Open query, _

            objConnection2, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText



        'For access database connection

        query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1] WHERE JUR = '" & JUR & "' AND WC = " & WC

        rows3.Open query, _

            objConnection3, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText



        ' DATA_STATUS = rows2.Fields("Status").Value

        ' DATA_SDATE = rows2.Fields("SDate").Value


        DATA_STATUS = rows3.Fields("Status").Value

        DATA_SDATE= rows3.Fields("SDate").Value









        if dateafter( SDATE, DATA_SDATE ) AND STATUS <> DATA_STATUS then

            'Need to update the data with the new value

            log("UPDATE: " & jur & ":" & wc & "has been changed to " & STATUS)

            query = "UPDATE [Sheet1] SET [STATUS] = '" & STATUS & "', [SDATE] = 

'" & SDATE & "' WHERE [JUR] = '" & JUR & "' AND [WC] = " & WC


            response.write(query)


            objConnection3.execute(query)

        END IF  

        rows2.close
    END IF
    rows.MoveNext
Loop


log("UPDATE COMPLETE")      
        %>

<!--#include file="footer.inc"-->
```

Thanks
Nik

Comment: I can't say for sure, while you close rows2, you leave open rows3

Comment: I would say you have the answer there @Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I have noticed that inside your loop you close the Recordset rows2, but you forget to close also the Recordset rows3. So, at the next loop after the first one, you get the error message when you try to reopen the rows3 Recordset.
A quick fix is:

```
    ....
    rows2.close 
    rows3.Close
END IF
```